# What are the components of a Web app?

Tags: web-applications, definition

As far as I understand a web application is a rich, dynamic webpage, containsing lots of user-generated content, achieved via certain code behind the static webpage.

What are the key components of the above? Is it OK to say that you require a standard HTML website and some sort of framework that would generate the dynamics for you from code written in some language (these include GWT, Play etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly you will find a web app with these components

- View Layer
- Business Layer
- Data Access Layer
- DO
- Error handling, security, logging

With HTML, Programming Language(Java, .Net, PHP) doing the server side work

Answer (score 1):

[image]Internet<->Load balancer (DNS, ngnix, switches)<->Web server ( node js) | -Memcache, My SQL ( database)